# Transfer Data from azure VM to Azure Website instance in realtime

Tags: asp.net, azure

I have a multi-tier ASP.NET Application and want to move that on the Azure Cloud.

Currently the workflow of the application is like this: 
User uploads a file, file is processed and the user gets live feedback of the calculations.

In the documentation of Azure i read, that for this a Azure Website for the Frontend and a Cloud Service or VM for the businesslogic would be a good appoach.

So all the calculations would be done in the VM. The uploaded Data from the users would be in a Blob Storage. The VM and the Azure Website can access them both then right?

For the live feedback the VM has to constantly send data back to the Azure Website instance which launched the calculation. is this possible in some way? I believe that it could be solved with webservices but is there a prettier way in the azure cloud?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The uploaded Data from the users would be in a Blob Storage. The VM
>   and the Azure Website can access them both then right?

Yes. The files stored in blob storage will be accessible to both Azure Website and VM.

> For the live feedback the VM has to constantly send data back to the
>   Azure Website instance which launched the calculation. is this
>   possible in some way? I believe that it could be solved with
>   webservices but is there a prettier way in the azure cloud?

Again, this is possible. One way to handle this communication is by utilizing the messaging infrastructure available in Azure. You could either use `Azure Queues` or `Azure Service Bus Queues`. The way it would work is that the VM processing the file will post a message in a queue (about its progress/completion/failure etc.). Website will constantly poll this queue for messages and based on the message it receives will take necessary actions.

Comment: Thank you! Thats the info i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The below link has a sample project built around Azure Websites, Storage (blob, tables) and worker roles which would suit your requirements, hope it helps you migrate your app !!

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Windows-Azure-Multi-Tier-eadceb36